# Codelite IDE doesn't launch on MacOS Ventura

Tags: codelite

I installed codelite following the instructions via Brew and everything went as normal, but when I try to open the app it just says "codelite closed unexpectedly".

I've tried to look for solutions but the only ones I could find are from 2020 and they talk about deleting a folder that isn't in my computer. Also deleting and reinstalling doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install using brew. Go to the Codelite archives and install version 14.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).